# How to stop Linux "xdg-open" or "gio open" launching Atom instead of file manager

Tags: linux, atom-editor, file-manager

I see strange behavior with Parrot OS VM when I open the file manager through the GUI or a Firefox download, or if I type `xdg-open .` or `gio open .` in the terminal, Atom opens instead of the default filemanager.

I don't know how this behaviour came to be, so I cannot propose a MWE. I'm sure it has something to do with default paths, but I don't know where to start.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Has anyone got an idea how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I suspect it's tied to the filemapping, based on the extensions of the files. It's got that sort of smell to it.

Comment: You think so ? because it happens when i try to open a folder also. Is there something i could print to check your feeling?